# Storing python list in django model using sqlite

Tags: django, django-models

I have a python list of integers and want to store it in an sqlite db.

```
myList = [T1_sum,T2_sum,T3_sum,T4_sum,T5_sum,T6_sum,T7_sum,T8_sum,T9_sum,T10_sum]
sortedlist = sorted(myList, reverse=True)
print(sortedlist)
```

How can I make a django model that will store this list?

Comment: Hi, do you want a model that just stores an array? What have you tried and what's the issue? Thanks

Comment: Yes, however I cannot find a django model type that takes an array for sqlite, There seems to be an Array field when using a postgres db but  I need a way to store this array while using an sqlite db

Comment: @kitchen800 what version of Django do you use? If it is >=3.1 you can use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) in any database.